# Primefaces Exporter Data type convert

Tags: primefaces

We are using PrimeFaces http://www.primefaces.org/ to export data in different format, pdf,excel ...

but in Excel we got a issue with the data type, for example if the the data is Integer in the Excel document the value appears how String and the viewer suggest change the value to number

how could we change the Data type in the exporter process ?

Code

```
<p:dataTable value="#{reportsBean.data}" var="reportResultRec"  widgetVar="resultWidgetVar" id="reportsResultId" paginator="true" rows="32" binding="#{reportsBean.dataTable}" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Usage report"/>
                </f:facet>
            <p:column width="37%" styleClass="tdTreeStyle">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Titles"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{reportResultRec.Name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column  width="25%" styleClass="tdTreeStyle">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Full Name"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{reportResultRec.fullName}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column width="13%" styleClass="tdTreeStyle">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Updated Date"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{reportResultRec.Timestamp}">
                  <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/YY"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column width="10%" styleClass="tdTreeStyle">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="View Count"/>
                </f:facet> 
                <h:outputText value="#{reportResultRec.viewCount}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column width="15%" styleClass="tdTreeStyle">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Recall Status"/>
                </f:facet>

            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>






<p:commandButton value="Export as Excel" ajax="false">
                            <p:dataExporter type="pdf" pageOnly="true" target="reportsResultId" fileName="Report"/>
                     </p:commandButton>
```

the reportResultRec.viewCount is convert to String and it is Integer and on the Excel viewer suggest change to Number

Comment: You should show us some code...

Comment: <p:commandButton value="Export as Excel" ajax="false">
      <p:dataExporter type="pdf" pageOnly="true" target="reportsResultId" fileName="Report"/>
     </p:commandButton>

Comment: You should write your code by editting your question. And please use some styling to make the code readable. You can delete your comments after editting your question with your code.

Comment: Now you got your first upvote ;)